# Sqlalchemy. How to set the defaul polymorphic innerjoin?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How to set the defaul polymorphic innerjoin?

```
class Some(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'some'
    @declared_attr
    def __mapper_args__(cls):
        return  {'polymorphic_identity': '%s' % cls.__tablename__,
                 'polymorphic_on': cls._type,
                 'with_polymorphic': '*',
                 'polymorphic_innerjoin': True # how to do it?
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

an INNER join is used if you actually query for that type specifically, no `with_polymorphic` needed:

```
sess.query(MySubClass).all()
```

If you are querying for `Some` objects (i.e. your base), that means you want objects that are also *not* of type `MySubClass`, so an OUTER join is necessary there.